# WebpackError with wow.js and Gatsby

Tags: webpack, gatsby, wow.js

When I try to build my gatsby project with wowjs it tell me :
'WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined' or
'"window" is not available during server side rendering.'

I tried a lot of thing like on this website: https://imedadel.me/fix-window-not-defined-gatsby but nothing work. If someone have face the same error it would be a pleasure to know how to get rid of it.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very common issue when dealing with Gatsby and some third-party modules or performing some calculations in your components.

`gatsby develop` occurs in the browser-side (summarizing) where there's a `window` object. On the other hand, `gatsby build` occurs on the server-side (your machine or your deploy system) where, for obvious reasons, [there's no `window` or other global objects](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/).

If you are using a `window` object in your component/pages, you just need to make an easy condition to check if the `window` object is available:

```
export const YourComponent = (props) => {

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined'){
     console.log('window width is', window.innerWidth)
  };

  return <div>I've checked the type of the window to make some calculations, preventing the code-breaking in the build time in SSR</div>;
};
```

If the issue comes from an external module of your code (third-party dependencies), you have two options:

- Replace the offending module in your `gatsby-node.js` by adding a new webpack configuration to add a `null` loader for that module:

  ```
  exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
    if (stage === "build-html") {
      actions.setWebpackConfig({
        module: {
            rules: [
            {
              test: /bad-module/,
              use: loaders.null(),
            },
           ],
        },
      })
    } 
  }
  ```

  Keep in mind that the rule is a regular expression that matches the folder name inside your `node_modules`, you'll need to change `/bad-module/` for the folder name of your broken dependency (that's why you need to add it between slashes (`/`)). In your case, it seems that you will need to change `/bad-module/` to `/wowjs/` but confirm the path.
- Use a [loadable](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components) library: this will load the dynamic modules that use `window` in the browser-side, once the compilation/build is done, not in the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering).